# wordpress wpbakery suddenly displaying shortcodes on front-end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, wpbakery

For an unknown reason my wordpress is showing shortcodes within the wpbakery instead of the image / buttons. It appears to me it converted image and button areas to paragraph sections then put the image shortcode in there. This is on all pages. Screenshots below. Any thoughts on why this might have happened, more importantly how to fix the issue?

[image: wpbakery backend screenshot]

[image: site front-end screenshot]

Comment: Since we don't access to your site..is there an update to the theme? Does a plugin control the shortcode? Has it been deactivated?

Comment: I believe these are the wpbakery shortcodes generated by wpbakery builder itself. For example normally I would click add image and after I choose an image it would appear in that left col section where the shortcode is now being displayed. Somehow that "image" section is now a paragraph section. 

If I add a new section everything works properly but the old entries got converted somehow.

Comment: Can you see if there is any error in de log? or in the console?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to WPBakery support?

Answer (score 0):

I did several things that one of them somehow fixed it. Not sure if any of these will help anyone in the future or not but here is what I did. I ended up rolling back the version of wordpress to before gutenburg using a rollback plugin, installed duplicator backed up and exported the database, I then disabled the rollback back to the latest version of wordpress, I installed a plugin that wasn't enabled previously called "UpSolution Core" through the "zephyr" theme menu. That never finished installing. I got an error stating I needed to disable wordfence to continue with the update. At this point the site returned to normal (before I disabled wordfence). But I continued with the installation by disabling wordfence, finishing the plugin install, then updating zephyr theme files it recommended after the install and re-enabled wordfence.

So oddly enough somewhere in the middle there it fixed the site. Very strange, somewhat reminds me of the old days when you just banged on the side of your computer and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

when this happens, you added a custom code to a random page that left open the php for the builder.

ORRRRRRRRRRRRR............ you slid your mouse finger in ftp while double clicking and shoved a file into an additional folder.

ORRRRRRR.... you pasted the text code into the visual tab.... but since this is wordpress level... most likely you double clicked a file into a folder in the theme or in wordpress trees

i would disable and enable each plugin in a row to check if they left a php tag open... then disable the theme.

REMEMBER never use a plugin at most you shouldnt have more than 6. wpbakery wpmailer contact form 7 wordfence possibly and thats it. add 6 if you have woo.

never use yoast. if your theme doesnt include title keyword description ... get rid of it... use qode.